# Why larastan raise error on relationLoaded method in resource file?

Tags: laravel, laravel-resource

In resource file app/Http/Resources/PostResource.php I use method :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class PostResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        $data = [
            'id' => $this->id,
            ...
            'mediaProp'=> $this->when($this->relationLoaded('mediaProp'), new MediaPropResource($this->mediaProp)),
        ];
```

But I got error when running larastan command :
Call to an undefined method App\Http\Resources\PostResource::relationLoaded()

I added PostResource class into phpstan.neon under universalObjectCratesClasses key:

```
includes:
    - ./vendor/nunomaduro/larastan/extension.neon

parameters:
    universalObjectCratesClasses:
        - Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource
        - App\Http\Resources\PostResource

    paths:
        - app/

    # Level 9 is the highest level
    level: 5

#    ignoreErrors:
#        - '#PHPDoc tag @var#'
#
#    excludePaths:
#        - ./*/*/FileToBeExcluded.php
#
#    checkMissingIterableValueType: false
```

But that does not help and i still got the same error. How can I fix it ?

```
"laravel/framework": "^10.8",
"nunomaduro/larastan": "^2.0",
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`relationLoaded` is a method that is defined in `HasRelationships` trait of Laravel. But PHPStan does not know the relation between a resource and model. So you need to add a `@mixin` annotation to your resource class. Like so:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

/** @mixin Post */
class PostResource extends JsonResource
....
```

Of course adjust the model namespace for your use case.

Comment: Yes, adding /** @mixin Post */ helped and I have this error any more. But I did not understand how this line influnced the issue? Please, explain.

Comment: Like I said `relationLoaded` is a method that is defined in `HasRelationships` trait of Laravel. But PHPStan does not know the relation between a resource and model. By adding `@mixin Post` you are telling PHPStan to "If you encounter an undefined method in `PostResource`, go look at `Post` model` And then PHPstan finds the correct method in `Post` model.